# Bi-Lipschitz invariance of the box-counting dimension.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, dimension-theory-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

I would like to prove that the box counting dimension is invariant under a bi-Lipschitz transformation. We have that $f$ is *bi-Lipschitz* if there exists $c_1, c_2$ such that $0 < c_1 \leq c_2 < \infty$ and $f$ satisfies:

$$c_1 |x-y| \leq |f(x)-f(y)| \leq c_2 |x-y|.$$

I can see how to prove that $\dim_Bf(F) \leq \dim_BF$, but I cannot see how to prove that $\dim_Bf(F) \geq \dim_BF$ in order to get that $\dim_Bf(F) = \dim_BF$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $F'=f(F)$. Then there is an inverse $f^{-1}: F'\to F$, which is also bi-Lipschitz. Apply the inequality you already have to the inverse: $\dim_B F\le \dim_B F'$.

Comment: Where is the proof that $f^{-1}$ is also bi-Lipschitz?

Comment: Here is a short proof: $(f^{-1})^{-1} = f$.